# Image texture is not showing on imported objects

Tags: texturing, image

Using Blender v2.8. When importing Vavefront obj or Stl and trying to assign an image texture, it doesn't show properly. At the same time, a native Blender object, like a cube from the screenshot with the same settings works as expected. Cannot find any differences in the settings between imported and native objects. Is it some kind of limitation, or imported objects needs to be processed differently?

BR
Oleg

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What exactly do you mean by "texture doesn't show properly"? If a texture doesn't show at all, it usually means the object isn't UV unwrapped.

Comment: Check the UV map. It seems to show the averaged color of the texture, this might happen when there is no UV map made for the object.